# How to distinguish "to fold the paper up / down / back / over"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> **[fold](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fold_1?q=fold)** [transitive] to bend something, especially paper or cloth, so that one
>   part lies on top of another part   fold something First, fold the
>   paper in half/in two.
>
> The bird folded its wings.
>
> a pile of neatly folded clothes
>
> **fold something up** He folded the map up and put it in his pocket.
>
> **fold something down** The blankets had been folded down.
>
> **fold something back** Don't fold back pages to mark your place in a book.
>
> **fold something over** Fold the dough over on top of itself.

Do we consider the meanings of "**up**", "**down**", "**back**" & "**over**" literally? (See the picture) or these adverbs can be used overlapped or interchangeably?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the words can be used literally as in your drawings. However, *fold up* can also mean to put away something that has been designed to fold to make it smaller for storage, such as a map or a deckchair.